# Spring Data Rest Validation Confusion

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-rest

Looking for some help with Spring data rest validation regarding proper handling of validation errors:

I'm so confused with the docs regarding spring-data-rest validation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#validation

I am trying to properly deal with validation for a POST call that tries to save a new Company entity

I got this entity:

```
@Entity
public class Company implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@NotNull
private String name;

private String address;

private String city;

private String country;

private String email;

private String phoneNumber;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "company")
private Set<Owner> owners = new HashSet<>();

public Company() {
    super();
}
```

...

and this RestResource dao

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource;

import com.domain.Company;

@RestResource
public interface CompanyDao extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Company,   Long> {


}
```

POST Request to api/Companies:

```
{
  "address" : "One Microsoft Way",
  "city" : "Redmond",
  "country" : "USA",
  "email" : "info@microsoft.com",
  "phoneNumber" : "(425) 703-6214"

}
```

When I issue a POST with a null name , I get the following rest response with httpcode 500

{"timestamp":1455131008472,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException","message":"Validation failed for classes [com.domain.Company] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]\nList of constraint violations:[\n\tConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=name, rootBeanClass=class com.domain.Company, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}\n]","path":"/api/companies/"}

I tried creating the following bean, but it never seems to do anything:

```
@Component(value="beforeCreateCompanyValidator")
public class BeforeCreateCompanyValidator implements Validator{

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return Company.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object arg0, Errors arg1) {
    System.out.println("xxxxxxxx");


}

}
```

and even if it did work, how would it help me in developing a better error response with a proper http code and understandable json response ?

so confused

using  1.3.2.RELEASE

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Answer (score 8):

---

@Mathias
it seems the following is enough for jsr 303 annotations to be checked and for it to auto return a http code of 400 with nice messages (I dont even need  BeforeCreateCompanyValidator or BeforeSaveCompanyValidator classes):

```
@Configuration
public class RestValidationConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter{

@Bean
@Primary
/**
 * Create a validator to use in bean validation - primary to be able to autowire without qualifier
 */
Validator validator() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}


@Override
public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingListener) {
    Validator validator = validator();
    //bean validation always before save and create
    validatingListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", validator);
    validatingListener.addValidator("beforeSave", validator);
}
```

}

400 response:

```
{
    "errors": [{
        "entity": "Company",
        "message": "may not be null",
        "invalidValue": "null",
        "property": "name"
    }, {
        "entity": "Company",
        "message": "may not be null",
        "invalidValue": "null",
        "property": "address"
    }]
}
```

Comment: True - it is enough if you only have annotated constraints - if you need more complex validation you would introduce a custom validator - and I just wanted to show how that would work.

Comment: Thanks for this answer this has been bugging me for almost and hour now.  I would have never guessed to make a LocalValidatorFactoryBean

Comment: RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter now should be RepositoryRestConfigurer.

Comment: @Bean LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
} // don't use Validator as return type, it may increase chances of conflict with other Validator bean.

Comment: v.addValidator("beforeCreate", validator);
        v.addValidator("beforeSave", validator);
        v.addValidator("beforeLinkSave", validator);
you may also need to add "beforeLinkSave".

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem is that the bean validation is happening too late - it is done on the JPA level before persist. I found that - unlike spring mvc - spring-data-rest is not doing bean validation when a controller method is invoked. You will need some extra configuration for this.

You want spring-data-rest to validate your bean - this will give you nice error messages responses and a proper http return code.

I configured my validation in spring-data-rest like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MySpringDataRestValidationConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    /**
     * Create a validator to use in bean validation - primary to be able to autowire without qualifier
     */
    Validator validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    //the bean name starting with beforeCreate will result into registering the validator before insert
    public BeforeCreateCompanyValidator beforeCreateCompanyValidator() {
        return new BeforeCreateCompanyValidator();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingListener) {
        Validator validator = validator();
        //bean validation always before save and create
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", validator);
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeSave", validator);
    }
}
```

When bean validation and/or my custom validator find errors I receive a 400 - bad request with a payload like this:

```
    Status = 400
    Error message = null
    Headers = {Content-Type=[application/hal+json]}
    Content type = application/hal+json
   Body = {
     "errors" : [ {
     "entity" : "siteWithAdminUser",
     "message" : "may not be null",
     "invalidValue" : "null",
     "property" : "adminUser"
     } ]
   }
```

Comment: super that worked a charm, btw is there anyway to automatically have jsr 303 annotations checked instead of the 'manual' stuff I am doing here:       @Override
 public void validate(Object object, Errors errors) {
  
  Company company = (Company)object;
  
  if(StringUtils.isEmpty(company.getName())){
   errors.rejectValue("name", "name.required", "Name field is missing");
  }
  

  
 }

Comment: I think if you have hibernate-validator on the classpath you should be able to use these constraint annotations as well - e.g. `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty`

Comment: I had wondered why your solution was still working for creates as well as updates (since I had not added a BeforeSaveCompanyValidator..).. so I started to experiment...  It seems I don't even need a BeforeCreateCompanyValidator or BeforeUpdateCompanyValidator because the LocalValidatorFactoryBean configuration bean handles it all. I will post the new version of your class in the original post above. It seems to work great but still a bit confused really...

Answer (score 4):

The answers by @Mathias and @1977 is enough for regular `Spring Data REST` calls. However in cases when you need to write custom `@RepositoryRestController`s using `@RequestBody` and `@Valid` JSR-303 annotations didn't work for me.

So, as an addition to the answer, in case of custom `@RepositoryRestController`s with `@RequestBody` and `@Valid` annotation I've added the following `@ControllerAdvice`:

```
/**
 * Workaround class for making JSR-303 annotation validation work for controller method parameters.
 * Check the issue <a href="https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-593">DATAREST-593</a>
 */

    @ControllerAdvice
    public class RequestBodyValidationProcessor extends RequestBodyAdviceAdapter {

        private final Validator validator;

        public RequestBodyValidationProcessor(@Autowired @Qualifier("mvcValidator") final Validator validator) {
            this.validator = validator;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean supports(final MethodParameter methodParameter, final Type targetType, final Class<? extends
                HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
            final Annotation[] parameterAnnotations = methodParameter.getParameterAnnotations();
            for (final Annotation annotation : parameterAnnotations) {
                if (annotation.annotationType().equals(Valid.class)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Object afterBodyRead(final Object body, final HttpInputMessage inputMessage, final MethodParameter
                parameter, final Type targetType, final Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
            final Object obj = super.afterBodyRead(body, inputMessage, parameter, targetType, converterType);
            final BindingResult bindingResult = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(obj, obj.getClass().getCanonicalName());
            validator.validate(obj, bindingResult);
            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                throw new RuntimeBindException(bindingResult);
            }

            return obj;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice ! Thank you :)