# How Spring Data REST return hibernate-JPA validation & server internal errors in json not stack trace

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-validator

I want to get JPA validation and server internal error on `JSON` format and not stack trace,

Using `Spring JPA data rest`

- **MyEntity Repository**

  ```
  @RepositoryRestResource(path = "entity")
  public interface MyEntityRepo extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {}
  ```
- **When post without `name, address` property i expect NOT NULL validation error.**

  ```
  curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"not passed and @NotNull","address":"not passed and @NotNull","city":"city","area":"area"}' http://localhost:8080/clinicfinder/api/entity
  ```
- **Current return :**

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.rest.core.RepositoryConstraintViolationException:Validation failed
>       org.springframework.data.rest.core.event.ValidatingRepositoryEventListener.validate(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener.java:179)
>       org.springframework.data.rest.core.event.ValidatingRepositoryEventListener.onBeforeCreate(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener.java:96)
>       org.springframework.data.rest.core.event.AbstractRepositoryEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractRepositoryEventListener.java:50)
>       org.springframework.data.rest.core.event.AbstractRepositoryEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractRepositoryEventListener.java:29)
>       org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
>       org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>       org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383)
>       org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:337)
>       org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.createAndReturn(RepositoryEntityController.java:484)
>       org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.postCollectionResource(RepositoryEntityController.java:272)
>       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>       org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
>       org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

- **Needed Return:**

  ```
  response 404, {"errors":[{"entity":"MyEntity","message":"may not be null","invalidValue":"null","property":"name"},{"entity":"MyEntity","message":"may not be null","invalidValue":"null","property":"address"}]}
  ```
- **Pom**

  ```
     <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
      <spring.data.jpa.version>1.11.1.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
  <spring.data.rest.webmvc.version>2.6.1.RELEASE</spring.data.rest.webmvc.version>
     </properties>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.41</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Spring Rest Repository -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.data.rest.webmvc.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- **web.xml**

  ```
  <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
          <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```
- **According to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35338751/1283715):**

Add this lines to `Spring-config.xml`

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<bean class="path.to.config.RestValidationConfiguration" />

@Configuration
public class RestValidationConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    /**
     * Create a validator to use in bean validation - primary to be able to
     * Autowire without qualifier
     */
    Validator validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingListener) {
        Validator validator = validator();
        // bean validation always before save and create
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", validator);
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeSave", validator);
    }
}
```

**But server keep returning `Stack trace` no `JSON` error format.**

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Is your class `RestValidationConfiguration` managed by Spring?

Comment: According to documentation [Combining Java and XML configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-combining)

`<context:annotation-config/><bean class="path.to.config.RestValidationConfiguration" />`  added to `spring-config.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks **@Alan Hay**, for suggest this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25222866/1283715) which working with me.